# How many of our users are on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, users

I am just curious; what percentage of total users does Stack Overflow make up? I know that I could count them, but with 200+ sites that seems inefficient.

I don’t care about active users or not, nor do I care about unique users.

Comment: Well are you counting a user active on two sites as 1 or 2 because if we have to count unique users that's somewhat harder.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites#users at first glance around 50% each.

Comment: Re *"I don't care about active users or not, nor do I care about unique users"*: That is the [company spirit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0yBf1JKTw8&t=3m0s)!

Comment: why don't you care about unique users? As I've shown in my answer, it's not _that_ hard to get a unique count for network accounts.

Comment: At the moment that really is the company spirit @This_is_NOT_a_forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Courtesy of [Count all users on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228564/997587) (answer by rene), from the last SEDE refresh, the result is 24,983,588.

Today, https://stackexchange.com/sites reports 20,080,969 users on Stack Overflow.

So roughly 80.38%.

Answer (score 1):

I copy-pasted https://stackexchange.com/sites#users to a text file `users_allsites.txt`. Then I used the following Python code:

```python
import re

multi = {"k": 1000, "m": 1000000}

users = open("users_allsites.txt", "r")
total_users = 0
for line in users:
    res = re.match("(\d+)([km]) users", line)
    if res:
       total_users += float(res.group(1)) * multi[res.group(2)]
print("total users:", int(total_users))
print("SO: ", 20000000/total_users)    
users.close()
```

This results in:

```
total users: 33752000
SO:  0.5925574780753733
```

Comment: so you assume that every user is only a user on a single network site?

Comment: oh. I just read the comment where the asker says they don't care about unique users. That's disappointing of them.

Comment: @starball this (sort of) answers the question of which percentage of (per-site) accounts on SE sites are SO accounts, which may be interesting as well (and for a certain definition of user you could say that a per-site account is a user). However, my answer was mostly intended as an attempt to implement the [comment of Robert Longson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387807/how-many-of-our-users-are-on-stack-overflow/387809?noredirect=1#comment1293340_387807) that you can calculate this from the `sites#users` page.